# Free double pointer struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, free

I want to put all MinHeapNode's into an array and free them after the program is done printing them.

Here is the code that creates the array and frees it:

```
void HuffmanCodes(int data[], int freq[], int size) {
        struct MinHeap *clear;
        int s = 0;
        struct MinHeapNode *nodes = malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeapNode) * ((4 * 2) - 1));
        struct MinHeapNode *root = buildHuffmanTree(data, freq, size, &clear);
        int arr[MAX_TREE_HT], top = 0;
        printCodes(root, arr, top, &nodes, &s);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                free(nodes[i]);
        }
        free(nodes);
        free(clear->array);
        free(clear);
}
```

Here is the code that grabs each MinHeapNode and puts it into nodes

```
void printCodes(struct MinHeapNode *root, int arr[], int top, struct MinHeapNode **nodes, int *s) {
        if (root->left) {
                arr[top] = 0;
                printCodes(root->left, arr, top + 1, nodes, s);
        }
        if (root->right) {
                arr[top] = 1;
                printCodes(root->right, arr, top + 1, nodes, s);
        }
        if (isLeaf(root)) {
                printf("%d: ", root->data);
                printArr(arr, top);
        }
        nodes[*s] = root;
        *s++;
}
```

Replacing the last two lines of **printCodes** with "free(root);" works, but I'm wanting to free it outside of the function.